# How to add custom close button in android recyclerview ltem?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want add custom close button in every item of rycycler view like this(blck color)

[image]

Comment: post your items xml for better answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1- you have to create new layout.xml like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_content"
        android:background="#aaa"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_close"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_delete"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

2- create CustomAdapter.class like below

```
public class CustomAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder>
{
List<YourModel>list;
@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int i)
{
    View 

 view=LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
    .inflate(R.layout.layout,parent,false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int i)
{
    holder.imgClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            //todo: your code here for close itemView
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount()
{
    return list.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    ImageView imgClose,imgContent;
    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView)
    {
        super(itemView);
        imgClose=itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_close);
        imgContent=itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_content);
        }
    }
}
```

And finally use your CustomAdapter

Comment: Thank you all.Sorry for late replay